# Using md-progress-linear inside md-dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I am trying to use md-progress-linear inside an md-dialog. The code for my progress bar is like below.

```
<div class="container">
    <md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="{{testCounter}}"></md-progress-linear>
    <div class="bottom-block">
      <span>Loading application libraries...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Normally its working fine, but when i use it inside a md-dialog its not working.

[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mznc7Yspv6JJK4twun90?p=preview)

In the above link the code i used is available, the liner bar in the home page is working fine. But when i click on open the modal is getting open, but the liner bar is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Reason that your visual didn't recognized right.
Main div in **dialog.html** doesn't have sizes.
Put in md-dialog:

```
 style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"
```

You will see that else works correctly.